# My Maven Project deviceUI has four components 1-ui 2- collector 3- api 4- reporting so i want to create 4 different profiles How it can be Done?

Tags: spring

I want to create four different profiles for each section and when one profile is running others are disabled

I tried creating profile in application.yml files and use @Profile annotations but it does not work

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a customed ComponentScanFilter.

```
public class ProfileScanFilter implements TypeFilter {

    private static final String PROFILE_1 = "compo_1";
    private static final String PROFILE_2 = "compo_2";
    private static final String PROFILE_3 = "compo_3";

    private static final Map<String, String> componentSectionPath =
            ImmutableMap.of(PROFILE_1, "com.compo_1", PROFILE_2, "com.compo_2", PROFILE_3, "com.compo_3");
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) {

        String[] activeProfiles = this.environment.getActiveProfiles();

        for (String p : activeProfiles) {
            if (componentSectionPath.containsKey(p)) {
                String className = metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName();
                if (className.startsWith(componentSectionPath.get(p))) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

then, add `@ComponentScan` on Server class

```
@ComponentScan(includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.CUSTOM, classes = ProfileScanFilter.class)})
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication{
}
```

Then give the application configuration like

> -Dspring.profiles.active=compo_1